# How to import cv2 in python project "Visual Studio 2015"?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, visual-studio-2015

I would like to start with OpenCV . I followed some tutorials for installing OpenCV in Windows.

After downloading and extracting OpenCV

First, I create environment variable and path

[image]

[image]

Then I moved to python in Visual Studio. I installed python and I started with a very simple tutorial, but I faced some problems with python.

1. First problem was with `numpy` module was not found. **solved**

   [image]
2. cv2 error I couldn't solved it, I followed instruction said that I need copy  `cv2.pyd` file in `..\Python34\Lib\site-packages`

[image]

afterword I tried to `>>> import cv2`

but I got this error

[image]

Thanks for all of you.

Comment: The "cv2.pyd" doesn't look like from your build. It dated back to April 2015. Check your build path to verify.

Comment: It' a good notes, but the file from build. The OpenCV folder 04/06/2015.  a big question mark over my head "?", but still I don't know why?